# Why is my JLabel (Icon) not rotating? (RotatedIcon)

Tags: java, jframe, icons, jlabel

I am making a game and the players icon should always rotate in the direction he walks but the icon does not rotate why is that? Here is the method for him rotating:

```
public static void turnPlayer(Direction d){
    if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
        RotatedIcon ri = new RotatedIcon(new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/Kaneki_walk.png")));;
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(90);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        System.out.println("Went as kaneki!");
        playerImage.setIcon(ri);
        playerImage.repaint();
        RepaintPlayer();
        p.setDirection(d);
    }
    if (pt == Playere.Touka){
        RotatedIcon ri = new RotatedIcon(new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png")));
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        System.out.println("Went as touka!");
        playerImage.setIcon(ri);
        playerImage.repaint();
        RepaintPlayer();
        p.setDirection(d);
    }
}
```

If you need the RepeintPlayer() method:

```
public static void RepaintPlayer(){
    if (p.isAttacking() == true){
        if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/Kaneki_hit.png"));
            playerImage.setIcon(img);
            System.out.println("WHY IT NO WORKING????? EVEN DO I PUT THISSS?");
        }
        if (pt == Playere.Touka){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/touka_hit.png"));
            playerImage.setIcon(img);
        }
    }else{
        if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/Kaneki_walk.png"));
            playerImage.setIcon(img);
        }
        if (pt == Playere.Touka){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png"));
            playerImage.setIcon(img);
        }
    }
    MovePlayer(p.getX(), p.getY());
    playerImage.repaint();
    f.repaint();
}
```

And if you need the whole class:

```
public class TheRealGame{

private static boolean running = false;
private static boolean paused = false;
private static boolean right = false, left = false, up = false, down = false;
private static JFrame f;
private static ArrayList<JLabel> ae = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
private static Player p;
private static Playere pt;
private static JLabel playerImage;
private static boolean info = false;
private static JLabel iy, ix, im, in, iu;

public static void main(Playere playertype){
    pt = playertype;
    p = new Player(pt);
    f = new JFrame();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(700, 700);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                up = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                left = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                down = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                right = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                p.attack();

            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F3){
                if (info == true){
                    info = false;
                    iy.setVisible(false);
                    ix.setVisible(false);
                    im.setVisible(false);
                    in.setVisible(false);
                    iu.setVisible(false);
                }else if (info == false){
                    info = true;
                    iy.setVisible(true);
                    ix.setVisible(true);
                    im.setVisible(true);
                    in.setVisible(true);
                    iu.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                up = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                left = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                down = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                right = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                p.attack();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
    playerImage = new JLabel();
    iy = new JLabel();
    ix = new JLabel();
    im = new JLabel();
    in = new JLabel();
    iu = new JLabel();
    iy.setLocation(0, 10);
    ix.setLocation(0, 20);
    im.setLocation(0, 30);
    in.setLocation(0, 40);
    iu.setLocation(0, 50);
    iy.setBounds((int) iy.getLocation().getX(), (int) iy.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    ix.setBounds((int) ix.getLocation().getX(), (int) ix.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    im.setBounds((int) im.getLocation().getX(), (int) im.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    in.setBounds((int) in.getLocation().getX(), (int) in.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    iu.setBounds((int) iu.getLocation().getX(), (int) iu.getLocation().getY(), 300, 15);
    f.add(ix);
    f.add(iy);
    f.add(im);
    f.add(in);
    f.add(iu);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setTitle("free play - tokyo ghoul");
    Start();
    p.Paint();
}
public static void resume(){
    if (paused == false){
        return;
    }
}
public static void pause(){
    if (paused == true){
        return;
    }
}
public static void Stop(){
    if (running == false){
        return;
    }
    running = false;
}
public static void Start(){
    running = true;

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int last = 0, u = 0;
            while (running == true){
                if (paused != true){
                    if (up == true){
                        p.move(p.getX(), p.getY()-1);
                        if (p.getDirection() != Direction.UP)
                            turnPlayer(Direction.UP);
                    }
                    if (down == true){
                        p.move(p.getX(), p.getY()+1);
                        if (p.getDirection() != Direction.DOWN)
                            turnPlayer(Direction.DOWN);
                    }
                    if (left == true){
                        p.move(p.getX()-1, p.getY());
                        if (p.getDirection() != Direction.LEFT)
                            turnPlayer(Direction.LEFT);
                    }
                    if (right == true){
                        p.move(p.getX()+1, p.getY());
                        if (p.getDirection() != Direction.RIGHT)
                            turnPlayer(Direction.RIGHT);
                    }
                    if (info == true){
                        int l = 10-last;
                        iy.setText("y: "+p.getY());
                        ix.setText("x: "+p.getX());
                        im.setText("enemys: "+ae.size());
                        in.setText("next enemy: "+l);
                        iu.setText("Updated "+u+" times.");
                        RefreshInfo();
                    }
                    if (p.getY() == +292){
                        p.move(p.getX(), -336);
                    }
                    if (p.getY() == -336){
                        p.move(p.getX(), 292);
                    }
                    if (p.getX() == +681){
                        p.move(-14, p.getY());
                    }
                    if (p.getX() == -14){
                        p.move(681, p.getY());
                    }
                    RepaintAllEnemys();
                    Enemy.UpdateAll();
                    RepaintPlayer();
                    if (info != true){
                        f.repaint();
                    }
                    if (last == 10){
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int x = 1+r.nextInt(2), y = 1+r.nextInt(2), distance = 1+r.nextInt(570), nx = 0, ny = 0;
                        if (x == 1){

                        }
                        last = 0;
                    }
                    last++;
                    u++;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void RefreshInfo(){
    f.remove(iy);
    f.remove(ix);
    f.remove(im);
    f.remove(in);
    f.remove(iu);
    f.add(ix);
    f.add(iy);
    f.add(im);
    f.add(in);
    f.add(iu);
    iy.setLocation(0, 10);
    ix.setLocation(0, 20);
    im.setLocation(0, 30);
    in.setLocation(0, 40);
    iu.setLocation(0, 50);
    iu.setBounds((int) iu.getLocation().getX(), (int) iu.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    iy.setBounds((int) iy.getLocation().getX(), (int) iy.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    ix.setBounds((int) ix.getLocation().getX(), (int) ix.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    im.setBounds((int) im.getLocation().getX(), (int) im.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    in.setBounds((int) in.getLocation().getX(), (int) in.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    f.repaint();
}

public static void UpdateAll(){

}

public static void Paint(JLabel imgs, int x, int y, File file){
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(file.getPath());
    imgs.setIcon(img);
    imgs.setBounds(x, y, img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight());
    imgs.setLocation(x, y);
    imgs.setVisible(true);

    f.add(imgs);
    imgs.setVisible(true);
}

public static void Repaint(JLabel l){
    f.remove(l);
    l.setBounds((int)l.getLocation().getX(), (int)l.getLocation().getY(), l.getWidth(), l.getHeight());
    f.add(l);
}

public static void addAE(JLabel l){
    ae.add(l);
}

public static void RepaintAllEnemys(){
    for (int i = 0; i < ae.size(); i++){
        ae.get(i).repaint();
    }
}

public static void MovePlayer(int x, int y){
    playerImage.setLocation(x, y);
    playerImage.repaint();
    f.repaint();
}

public static void RepaintPlayer(){
    if (p.isAttacking() == true){
        if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/Kaneki_hit.png"));
            playerImage.setIcon(img);
            System.out.println("WHY IT NO WORKING????? EVEN DO I PUT THISSS?");
        }
        if (pt == Playere.Touka){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/touka_hit.png"));
            playerImage.setIcon(img);
        }
    }else{
        if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/Kaneki_walk.png"));
            playerImage.setIcon(img);
        }
        if (pt == Playere.Touka){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png"));
            playerImage.setIcon(img);
        }
    }
    MovePlayer(p.getX(), p.getY());
    playerImage.repaint();
    f.repaint();
}

public static void paintplayer(){
    if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
        ImageIcon imgs = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/schoo/NewGame/kaneki_walk.png"));
        playerImage.setIcon(imgs);
        playerImage.setBounds(p.getX(), p.getY(), imgs.getIconWidth(), imgs.getIconHeight());
        playerImage.setLocation(274, 277);
        playerImage.setVisible(true);
        f.add(playerImage);
        playerImage.setVisible(true);
    }
    if (pt == Playere.Touka){
        playerImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png")));
        playerImage.setBounds(p.getX(), p.getY(), new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png")).getIconWidth(), new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png")).getIconHeight());
        playerImage.setLocation(274, 277);
        playerImage.setVisible(true);
        f.add(playerImage);
        playerImage.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public static void turnPlayer(Direction d){
    if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
        RotatedIcon ri = new RotatedIcon(new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/Kaneki_walk.png")));;
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(90);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        System.out.println("Went as kaneki!");
        playerImage.setIcon(ri);
        playerImage.repaint();
        RepaintPlayer();
        p.setDirection(d);
    }
    if (pt == Playere.Touka){
        RotatedIcon ri = new RotatedIcon(new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png")));
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.UP && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.RIGHT && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.DOWN && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        if (d == Direction.LEFT && p.getDirection() == Direction.UP)
            ri.setDegrees(Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2+Math.PI / 2);
        System.out.println("Went as touka!");
        playerImage.setIcon(ri);
        playerImage.repaint();
        RepaintPlayer();
        p.setDirection(d);
    }
}

public enum Direction{
    LEFT, UP, RIGHT, DOWN;
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a simple program with a JLabel containing the Icon and then a couple of buttons like "Left" and "Right" that will rotate the Icon. Learn how to use the Icon first. In you last question it was specifically mentioned that you set the degrees (not the radians)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but I have a guess.

I can see that you always invoke `RepaintPlayer()` right after `playerImage.setIcon(ri);` in your `turnPlayer` method. And`RepaintPlayer()` sets the icon to be the original *.png* image with this call: `playerImage.setIcon(img);`.

I suggest you should remove the `RepaintPlayer()` method call for now to see if that makes the icon turn as expected or not. (You are probably going to have a hard time testing all the from-to direction combinations.)